# How to access multiple return values in restype?

Tags: python, go, ctypes

I am writing a Go program like the below:

```
package main

import (
    "C"
)

//export getData
func getData(symbol string, day string, month string, year string) (string, string) {
    return "A", "B"
}

func main() {

}
```

In Python, I am doing this:

```
import ctypes
library = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./deribit.so')
get_data = library.getData

# Make python convert its values to C representation.
get_data.argtypes = [ctypes.c_wchar, ctypes.c_wchar,ctypes.c_wchar,ctypes.c_wchar]
get_data.restype = [ctypes.c_wchar,ctypes.c_wchar]

d,c = get_data("symbol", "day","month","year")
print(d,c)
```

And it gives the error:

```
  get_data.restype = ctypes.c_wchar,ctypes.c_wchar
TypeError: restype must be a type, a callable, or None
```

Comment: If instead of Go and Python, you were interfacing between Go and C, then what would the C code to do it look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [cgo docs](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo):

> Go functions can be exported for use by C code in the following way:
>
> ```
> //export MyFunction
> func MyFunction(arg1, arg2 int, arg3 string) int64 {...}
>
> //export MyFunction2
> func MyFunction2(arg1, arg2 int, arg3 string) (int64, *C.char) {...}
> ```
>
> They will be available in the C code as:
>
> ```
> extern GoInt64 MyFunction(int arg1, int arg2, GoString arg3);
> extern struct MyFunction2_return MyFunction2(int arg1, int arg2, GoString arg3);
> ```
>
> found in the _cgo_export.h generated header, after any preambles
> copied from the cgo input files. **Functions with multiple return values
> are mapped to functions returning a struct.**

A function that returns multiple values gets mapped to a function returning a struct. Read the `_cgo_export.h` generated header to see the struct definition; the documentation is unclear on what the struct definition looks like. I would *guess* it just contains all return values in the order the function returns them, with some unspecified auto-generated names, but the documentation doesn't say.

(`GoString` in the above code should probably say `_GoString_`; this is the only part of the linked documentation page that writes `GoString` without underscores. It's probably an error.)

---

However, you have other problems, both of which will prevent you from calling your `getData` function.

The first problem is that a Go string is not a `char *`. It is its own separate type. C code can interact with Go strings through the `_GoString_` type and several helper functions, but creating Go strings from outside Go is unsupported.

The second is that due to Go garbage collection, there are many restrictions on how non-Go code is allowed to interact with pointers to Go memory. One of the restrictions is that Go code cannot return Go strings to non-Go code, or return anything else that contains pointers to Go memory. Your `getData` returns Go strings, so it cannot be called from outside Go.