# Strugglign to pass string and int parameters from Python to Go library

Tags: python, go, ctypes, cgo

I have the go library with the following signature:

```
//export getData
func getData(symbol string, day int, month string, year int) string {
    return "getData2"
}
```

In Python I did like the below:

```
import ctypes
library = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib.so')
get_data = library.getData

# Make python convert its values to C representation.
get_data.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int]
get_data.restype = ctypes.c_wchar

# j= get_data("BTC".encode('utf-8'), "3", "JAN".encode('utf-8'), "23".encode('utf-8'))
j= get_data(b"XYZ", 3, "JAN", 23)
print(j)
```

and it gives the error

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

I am using Python 3.9

**Updates**

I made changes in Go Function Signature like this:

```
func getData(symbol, day, month, year *C.char) *C.char {
    var instrumentName, combine string
    x := C.GoString(symbol) + "-" + C.GoString(day) + C.GoString(month) + C.GoString(year)
    log.Println(x)
 ....
```

And in Python like this:

```
get_data = library.getData

# Make python convert its values to C representation.
# get_data.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p]
get_data.restype = ctypes.c_wchar_p

j= get_data("BTC", "3", "JAN", "23")
# j= get_data(b"BTC", 3, "JAN", 23)
print(j.decode('utf-8'))
```

No parameter issue but the issue I am getting that it is fetching first param of each param in Go code, that is:

```
x := C.GoString(symbol) + "-" + C.GoString(day) + C.GoString(month) + C.GoString(year)
    log.Println(x)
```

So instead of printing `BTC-3JAN23`, it prints `B-3J2`

Comment: I don't know Go so other things could be wrong as well, but your `.argtypes` don't match the arguments (specifically the 3rd parameter as the error states), and according to the [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74980261/235698) returning Go strings isn't supported for C interfacing.

Comment: Go strings and C strings are not the same. You must convert between them when crossing the language barrier. The `cgo` [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo) has some information about this.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco question updated, can you please help?

Comment: Why is `get_data.argtypes = ...` commented out? Also, you shouldn't be using `wchar_t`, which is for "wide characters".

Answer (score 1):

On line 4 you did `get_data.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int]` but since the 3rd argument is a string then it should be `get_data.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_int]`

Comment: Now it gives a new error: `ValueError: character U+100392f7 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).